# Verizon FiOS router and a switch

Tags: networking, router, fios

I am moving my FiOS router to my office, and will need to run some extra cables. I would like to install a switch in the basement, and have all the lines terminate there, but I am not sure of the best way to handle it.

Here's what my current network looks like (not showing the wireless devices)
 [image: Current Network setup]

Here's what I have in mind for my network at the end. The dotted red line is what I would like to do, but I doubt it will work. The dashed blue line is what I am pretty sure will work. However, aesthetically, I would not like this setup. I'd need to have one cable go into my office, and then another go back out.

[image: Proposed Network Setup]

I guess at its most basic, my question is this. Does the FiOS router always need a direct connection to the box outside, or can it somehow go through a switch.

Comment: You are going to have to connect the outside box, first to the modem you were provided, then to your switch and/or any other routers you might have.  The configuration you want isn't possible.

Comment: Do the wires even fit, that way? Outside box to router would be a coaxial cable or similar.

Comment: You have to already have an ip address, in order to use a switch, which won't be the case if the modem doesn't come first.

Answer (score 1):

Outside FiOS box means Optical Network Terminal (ONT) should always be directly connected to FiOS Router.  ONT has direct connection with OLT (Optical Line Terminal), Verizon office.

Reason:-

First off, NAT (Network Address Translation) should be completed on the router and only then the clients connected to the router (wired or wireless) devices will be able to obtain Private IP addresses from DHCP Server.

However, you can connect switch to the BHR (Broadband Home Router) once a connection has been established between ONT and FiOS Router.

Network Diagram:-

O L T. -  - - O N T - - - FiOS Router- - - Switch